# How to create horizontal line in Markdown (using hexo framework)

Tags: markdown, hexo

I'm using the hexo framework and tried adding "---" or "***" in my .md file to get a horizontal line to show up, but it's not working.

Also tried enabling gfm markdown in my _config.yml file:

marked:
  gfm: true
  pedantic: false
  sanitize: false
  tables: true
  breaks: true
  smartLists: true
  smartypants: true
  modifyAnchors: ''
  autolink: true

Any clues? Or is there a way to embed HTML tags to posts?

Comment: `<hr/>` should work in most Markdown editors

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm using a markdown renderer (hexo-renderer-marked) but it doesn't seem like the html tag is rendering in my posts.

Comment: Have you checked the HTML output? Perhaps the `hr` tag is there but not being displayed due to some CSS rules. Use "view source" in your browser to confirm whether the `hr` tag is in the output.

Answer (score 110):

`---` on a line by itself works for me.

I'm using the [Icarus](https://github.com/ppoffice/hexo-theme-icarus) theme, which displays the separator as a dashed line:

[image]

As @Waylan commented, your CSS rules are probably preventing your horizonal line to display.

I've also found that preceding the `---` line with a `<br>` line prevents the horizontal line from displaying.

Comment: If somebody is looking to place the horizontal line right after the `<br>`, simply replace `<br>` with `<hr>`. This was particularly helpful for me within tables.

Answer (score 54):

tripledash `---` has to precede and follow with empty lines to take effect like so

```
---
```

thus results in solid line in Markdown

Answer (score 17):

I know this is old, but for anyone else that runs into this problem what worked for me was to use three underscores instead of three dashes.

<kbd>___</kbd> vs. <kbd>---</kbd>

Comment: I had to do it this way too, because the md file could not process more than one `---`

Comment: Thanks! both of them works for me with jekyll, however there is a formatting issue on vscode using dashes because the formatter considers three dashes as a begin of front matter section.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is old, but I would like to add one thing with markdown. If you put a horizontal line with no new line right after a paragraph like this:

```
This is text! <!--No new line after paragraph-->
---
```

The output will be:

### This is text!

with the text bolded.

In order to create a horizontal line, you need to put a new line between the paragraph and the 
`---`, like this:

```
This text is also text! <!-- New line here... -->

---

This is separated text! <!-- ... and new line here. -->
```

which in markdown makes:

This text is also text!

---

This is separated text!

Comment: --- creates a horizontal line. Thanks!